# server = ThreadingHTTPServer((host, port), Handler) TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'server'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.6

How to resolve this error please?

```
server = ThreadingHTTPServer((host, port), Handler)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'server'
```

here it's my code:

```
httpd = ThreadingTCPServer(("", port), Handler)
# same error with:
httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(("", port), Handler)
```

I am trying to make a multithreaded server with:
`http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`

I looked at sample codes and most of them cause this error.

Comment: Can you show the complete code and traceback?

Comment: Thank's you so much for your help i found the answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that in most of the codes making multiThread servers they implemented the class like this:

```
class ThreadingHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn,http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    pass
```

But surely now with python 3 we have to implement it like this:

```
class ThreadingHTTPServer (ThreadingMixIn, http.server.HTTPServer):
     pass
```